# T-SQL - select top 10; one from each group

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Newbie here.

I have list of companies with state_name (and other now unrelevant data). I'm trying to write a query which returns a top 10 list where companies appear only once with the state_name and COUNT(*) where COUNT(*) is the highest.

This is where I am at the moment:

```
SELECT TOP 10
    COUNT(*) [# of Complaints]      
    ,state_name
    ,company
FROM dbo.Consumer_Complaints
GROUP BY company,state_name
ORDER BY [# of Complaints] DESC
```

This returns the following:

```
# of Complaints state_name company
--------------- ---------- ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
801             CA         Bank of America
776             CA         Wells Fargo & Company
648             TX         Experian
594             CA         Experian
580             TX         Equifax
566             FL         Bank of America
539             CA         JPMorgan Chase & Co.
518             CA         Equifax
499             FL         Wells Fargo & Company
481             TX         TransUnion Intermediate Holdings, Inc.
       ...
```

Ideally this is how it would look like in the end:

```
 # of Complaints state_name company
 --------------- ---------- ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    801             CA         Bank of America
    776             CA         Wells Fargo & Company
    648             TX         Experian
    580             TX         Equifax
    539             CA         JPMorgan Chase & Co.
    481             TX         TransUnion Intermediate Holdings, Inc.
   ...
```

What would be the ideal solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ROW_NUMBER()` and a subquery:

```
SELECT TOP 10 c.*
FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) as [# of Complaints],      
             state_name, company
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY company ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) as seqnum
      FROM dbo.Consumer_Complaints
      GROUP BY company, state_name
     ) c
WHERE seqnum = 1
ORDER BY [# of Complaints] DESC;
```